# Image scaling issue

Tags: html, css, image, pikachoose

I'm having an image sizing issue here: http://goo.gl/UYUuJL in making the images scale so that the image height fills 100% of the div "pika-stage" proportionately. I apologize is this has been answered elsewhere.

Here's the CSS:

```
    .pika-stage {
         position: relative; 
         text-align: center; 
         height: auto; 
         max-height: 410px; 
         overflow: hidden; 
         background: #000;
    }

    .pika-stage img {
         height: 100% !important;
         position: relative;
    }
```

Take for example the top right most thumbnail in this gallery: original size: 1364 × 2921 (there's supposed to be an elephant atop the legs). Once the thumbnail is clicked it doesn't  scale the image enough to fit the entire thing proportionately within the "pika-stage" div. Could this scaling be somehow overridden with the media image sizes?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please check your image in your scr folder.

Comment: are you talking about [this](http://testsite.brentthelendesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Ak-Ship-on-Forearm-520x410.jpg) image been repeated??

Comment: That image isn't repeated, it's a collage type shot. I'm trying to get the images to scale into the div area. I don't mind if there's a black background on some of the more vertical images.

Answer (score 0):

Define `height: 100%` to your `.pika-stage` instead of `height: auto;`

```
.pika-stage {position: relative; text-align:center; height:100%; max-height:410px; overflow:hidden; background: #000;}
```